Bluetooth from Docker in Windows
Theoretically the solution was already there, someone did it and documented.
But I've found that integrating a Bluetooth Dongle with Windows is not so trivial as commented there. Maybe it is because the stack has upgraded and since this is a 2 year old post, perhaps some new flaws have arisen.
I've tried to implement most ideas I've read both here and Github. Most questions regarding this topic are based on a Linux host (like Raspberry Pi), not over Windows/WSL.
For example this: Accessing Bluetooth dongle from inside Docker?
I've read plenty of posts in Github being this one of the most thorough.
Now I'm going to describe and reproduce the steps taking based on the suggesting and how it's not working despite all ideas I've read so far.
The stack:

WSL version: 2.3.14.0 (I'm not using 2.3.17, the latest, because I need the drivers in Kernel 6.6 for the Bluetooth dongle, and a Custom Kernel provokes some issues in Docker Desktop)
Kernel version: 6.6.36.3-1
Docker Desktop: 4.33.1
Docker: 27.1.1
USBIPD: 4.3.0


First making it work in the WSL2. After setting up USBIPD and everything, everything is perfectly fine working in the WSL host:

# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 10d7:b012 Actions general adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller F4:4E:FC:8E:1A:30 Pairable: yes

$ hciconfig hc0
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: F4:4E:FC:8E:1A:30  ACL MTU: 679:6  SCO MTU: 240:20
        UP RUNNING
        RX bytes:1825 acl:0 sco:0 events:110 errors:0
        TX bytes:4419 acl:0 sco:0 commands:97 errors:0


Preparing the Docker image:

2.1 Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y bluez bluetooth usbutils

COPY docker_entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/docker_entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT sh /usr/src/app/docker_entrypoint.sh

2.2 docker_entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

service dbus start
bluetoothd &
/bin/bash

2.3 Stopping Bluetooth service in the WSL host sudo service bluetooth stop
$ bluetoothctl
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...

$ sudo hcitool lescan
Could not open device: No such device

2.4. Build the image and start it with:
docker -t myimage .
docker run --rm --net=host --privileged -it myimage

This is the full setup recommended in 100% of the places I've seen. Theoretically now that the WSL host is not serving Bluetooth it should work straight on the docker image:
First, the device is there:
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 10d7:b012 Actions general adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Second, bluetoothd, despite being run in the entrypoint is not actually running:
# service bluetooth status
 * bluetooth is not running

# bluetoothd -n
bluetoothd[65]: Bluetooth daemon 5.72
bluetoothd[65]: src/adapter.c:adapter_init() Failed to access management interface
bluetoothd[65]: src/main.c:main() Adapter handling initialization failed

# hciconfig hc0
Can't open HCI socket.: Address family not supported by protocol

# lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             741376  6 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           12288  1 bluetooth

# dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[   75.485496] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   75.485527] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   75.485532] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   75.485534] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   75.485538] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 3675.898623] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 3675.898630] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 3695.249669] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting command is advertised, but not supported.
[ 3695.249672] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Read Transmit Power Level command is advertised, but not supported.
[ 3695.249674] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Set Random Private Address Timeout command is advertised, but not supported.
[ 3695.364291] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22

I also tried running the image sharing system bus socket, instead of using the --net=host thing with:
$ docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/dbus/:/run/dbus/:z --privileged myimage
 * Removing stale PID file /var/run/dbus/pid.
 * Starting system message bus dbus 

But the same results as the ones above.
Although everything seems to be perfectly in order hardware-wise, it's not within the docker container. I have spent countless hours reading posts unsuccessfully, and now I'm giving up, at this point I'm completely lost, and have not found any more references to keep moving forward.
